# Running multiple Teradata SQL queries at once with python

Tags: python, pandas, teradata

I have connected to Teradata with sqlalchemy and am looking to execute multiple SQL statements at once. The queries are simply, but here would be an example

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
;
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
;
```

I want both of these queries to kick off at the same time instead of running the first one then the second one.

My sqlalchemy connection is as follow

```
query = f"""
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
;
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
;
"""
create_engine(<connection string>)
pd.read_sql(query, create_eingine)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what is the best way to achieve your goal, but maybe a modification of the query would be working for you:

    INSERT INTO TABLE_A
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM TABLE_B WHERE ID IN (6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

Comment: Well, if sqlalchemy submits this SQL string as-is, it will be a Multi-Statement Request (MSR). The optimizer will try to execut them in parallel if possible, Explain should reveal it.

Comment: It’s teradata, so it only does them one at a time. Since I have like 50 of them I washed them all to kick off together so it’s not churning and burning for a day